# Consulta que a veces funciona y a veces no

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola tengo una consulta que me trae los usuarios segun una fecha, el problema es que los usuarios han ido creciendo y a veces la consulta falla: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://rest.api.cdf.cl/api/v1/usuarios/activos/2020-09-06/list' from origin 'http://10.3.75.104' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Lo cierto es que no son los header porque todo funcionaba perfecto solo es ahora que subieron la cantidad de registros y colapsa la consulta...

alguna ayuda? alguna ideqa???de antemano gracias....

Comment: Estas utilizando la librería `cors`?

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser un cruce de dominios utiliza cors seguramente al aumentar la demanda de tus peticiones el host estará balanceando la carga y te este dando el error

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé, _CORS_ nada tiene que ver con la cantidad de datos a devolver, simplemente niega acceso si la petición proviene de un origen diferente y los encabezados no son apropiados o el destino no está configurado para aceptar el origen.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de problema de balanceador de carga, que alguno de los dominios no apruebe el cors y te lance el error